# transfer from ETHER.LI to another wallet

Tags: ether.li

I'm new to this business. I tried to make my first transfer from ETHER.LI to another wallet and the message is:

Request initiated by 0xc1588b9c4da3f992bd2b17b49f50719e32783c31

And nothing else happens. 
The balance does not decrease.
I do not know what to do.
Somebody help me please

Answer (score 0):

Ether.li have to approval this transaction. Or you can by yourself approve this on Parity.